# R sample until a condition is met

Tags: r, sample

So i have the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(45L, 17L, 28L, 26L, 18L, 41L, 26L, 20L, 
23L, 31L, 48L, 23L, 32L, 18L, 30L, 11L, 26L)), .Names = "V1", row.names = c("24410", 
"26526", "26527", "43264", "63594", "125630", "148318", "245516", 
"269500", "293171", "301217", "400294", "401765", "520084", "545501", 
"564914", "742654"), class = "data.frame")
```

The rownames represent parcels and V1 shows the number of examples per parcel I can draw from.
What I want is to take a sample from every parcel proportional to the number of examples available, whereabouts in the end ending up with a total of 400 examples per parcel. The idea being not to oversample one parcel as respect to the others.

The dataset from which the sampling is going on is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vub0lePhSm0ZQ3MnH-lbLENnQP_CN6ax/view?usp=sharing).

So far the code looks like this:

```
df <- read.csv('/data/samplefrom.csv')
df.training <- data.frame()
n <- 400

for(crop in sort(unique(df$code_surveyed))){
  for (bbch_stage in sort(unique(df$bbch))) {
    df.int <- df[df$bbch==bbch_stage & df$code_surveyed == crop,]
    df.int <- df.int[!is.na(df.int$name),]
    rawnum <- nrow(df[df$bbch==bbch_stage & df$code_surveyed == crop,])
    if(rawnum >= n){
      df.bbch.slected<-df[df$bbch==bbch_stage & df$code_surveyed == crop,]
      df.bbch.slected.sampled<-df.bbch.slected[sample(nrow(df.bbch.slected), n),] #(round(n_bbch*length(which(df$bbch==bbch_stage))))), ]
      df.training<-rbind(df.training,df.bbch.slected.sampled)
    }

  }
}
```

What this does is to sample 400 examples at random for each crop + bbch_stage combination (understand this as a composite variable). That's all fine and dandy, but I want to be able to control from which parcel (variable `objectid`) do the examples come from. In essence an extra filtering step while sampling.

I've tried a few attempts with `while` and `repeat` statements and also with the `stratified` function from `devtools`, but none of them seem to produce what I'm after.

Comment: 400 examples from all the parcels belonging to each class. The class in question is the crop+bbch_stage combination. If you execute the little snipped with the samplefrom.csv it will become much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some ups and downs I got to this point:

```
df.training<-data.frame()
for (crop in unique(df$code)) {
  df.crop.slected<-df[df$code==crop,]
  df.crop.slected.sampled <- data.frame()
  while(nrow(df.crop.slected.sampled) < 400){
    for(parcel in 1:length(unique(df.crop.slected$objectid))){
      df.crop.slected.pacel <- df.crop.slected[df.crop.slected$objectid == unique(df.crop.slected$objectid)[parcel],]
      df.crop.slected.pacel <- df.crop.slected.pacel[sample(nrow(df.crop.slected.pacel), 1), ]
      if(! df.crop.slected.pacel$name %in% df.crop.slected.sampled$name){
        df.crop.slected.sampled <- rbind(df.crop.slected.sampled, df.crop.slected.pacel)
      }

    }
  }
  df.training<-rbind(df.training,df.crop.slected.sampled)
}
```

while certainly not the most elegant, it does the job. Would still very much appreciate if someone can direct me to a function for stratified sampling that allows for this in an easier way.